# how to optimize the graph ggplot with geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I am a beginner under R, I created a graph that superimposes the temperatures to the precipitations, under ggplot with `geom_bar` as an option. However, I use the option `position = position_nudge (x = 0.4)`, so that the graphics are not on top of each other. When I use this option, it completely changes the way of calculating.

For example, as you will see below, I would like to have on the barplots on the right dates, a barplot until 31/30. Do you know how to solve this problem? Thank you in advance for your precious help.

Below are my table and my code.

```
SOUNAME year_month  pre_type    pre_value   tem_type    tem_value   nb_species
WATERFORD (TYCOR)   2014-04 NONE    14  V_COLD  0   NA
WATERFORD (TYCOR)   2014-04 HEAVY   3   COLD    30  8
WATERFORD (TYCOR)   2014-04 LIGHT   7   HOT 0   NA
WATERFORD (TYCOR)   2014-04 MEDIUM  6   MEDIUM  0   NA
WATERFORD (TYCOR)   2014-05 NONE    15  V_COLD  0   NA
WATERFORD (TYCOR)   2014-05 HEAVY   3   COLD    31  17
WATERFORD (TYCOR)   2014-05 LIGHT   10  HOT 0   NA
WATERFORD (TYCOR)   2014-05 MEDIUM  3   MEDIUM  0   NA
WATERFORD (TYCOR)   2014-06 NONE    17  V_COLD  0   NA
WATERFORD (TYCOR)   2014-06 HEAVY   2   COLD    17  NA
WATERFORD (TYCOR)   2014-06 LIGHT   9   HOT 13  NA
WATERFORD (TYCOR)   2014-06 MEDIUM  2   MEDIUM  0   NA

ggplot(data = complet_w, 
       aes(x = complet_w$year_month, 
           y = complet_w$pre_value, 
           fill = complet_w$pre_type, 
           width=0.5), 
       stat = "identity") + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  xlab("date") + 
  ylab ("Number of days of precipitation") + 
  ggtitle("Precipitation per month") + 
  labs(fill = "Frequency") +
  geom_bar(data=complet_w,
           aes(x=complet_w$year_month, 
               y=complet_w$tem_value, 
               fill=complet_w$tem_type, 
               width=0.1), 
           stat = "identity", 
           position = position_nudge(x=0.4)) + 
  xlab("date") + 
  ylab("Number of days of temperature") + 
  ggtitle("Temperature per month") + 
  labs(fill = "Frequency")
```

Below is my result. I would like all bars to be 30-31. Is it possible?

[image: result]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, do you want all the bars to have the same height?

Comment: "I would like all bars to be 30-31" What do you mean exactly? Like each bar should cover a full month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember your previous question. I think you are looking for something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)      #To use melt
View(TEMP_PREC_BIRR)
View(TEMP_BIRR)
write.csv(TEMP_PREC_BIRR,"Data1.csv")
write.csv(TEMP_BIRR,"Data2.csv")
Data1=melt(TEMP_PREC_BIRR,id.vars="year_month")
Data2=melt(TEMP_BIRR,id.vars="year_month")
Data=rbind(Data1,Data2)
Data=Data[!(Data$variable=="SOUNAME"),]
View(Data)
Data=read.csv("Data1.csv")
View(Data)
ggplot(Data,aes(x=year_month,y=Data$precipitation_value_,fill=Data$precipitation_type))+
  geom_col()

ggplot(data = TEMP_PREC_BIRR, aes(x = TEMP_PREC_BIRR$year_month, 
                                  y = TEMP_PREC_BIRR$precipitation_value, 
                                  fill = TEMP_PREC_BIRR$precipitation_type,width=0.2)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = as.numeric(year_month)+0.25, 
               y = TEMP_PREC_BIRR$precipitation_value, 
               fill = TEMP_PREC_BIRR$precipitation_type),
           stat = "identity",position = position_stack()) + 
  xlab("date") + ylab ("Number of days of precipitation") + 
  ggtitle("Precipitation per month - BIRR") + labs(fill = "Frequency")+
  geom_bar(data=TEMP_BIRR,aes(x=as.numeric(TEMP_BIRR$year_month)-0.25,
                                 y=TEMP_BIRR$temperature_value,
                                 fill=TEMP_BIRR$temperature_type), stat = "identity",position = position_stack()) +
  xlab("date") + ylab("Number of days of temperature") + 
  ggtitle("Temperature per month - BIRR") + labs(fill = "Frequency")+
  theme(panel.background=element_blank())
```

[image: Output Plot]

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `position_nudge()` to `position_stack()`. But to get the 2 graphs in one plot you would have to change the aesthetics of the `geom_bar()` separately.

Use your code like this:

```
#Change xval.yval and xlab to your requirement

ggplot(Dataname)+geom_bar(stat="identity",aes(x=as.numeric(xval)-0.25,y=yval))+
geom_bar(stat="identity",aes(x=as.numeric(xval)+0.25,y=yval))+
scale_x_discrete(labels= xlabs)   #because you have renamed them using aes()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's perfect!! Thank you very much !

Comment: If it solved your problem consider accepting the answer.

Comment: do you have any knowledge of shiny?

Comment: Yes but before I have a question, please. Do you know how we can change the axes of the abscissa? I would like have 05/2014 fr example and not 1, is it possible?

Comment: Actually, I would like to know that myself, I've never wanted to rename it. But now you have to so post it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things going on that don't quite fit with `ggplot`'s setup:

1. You've set labels and the title multiple times. If you have a plot, then say `ggtitle("Title 1") + ggtitle("Title 2")`, only Title 2 will be displayed, because the last call overrides any previous ones. Same with your calls of `xlab`, etc.
2. You have multiple instances of `geom_bar`, but they're doing essentially the same thing. This generally signals that your data should be in a long format so you can map some variable to an aesthetic that you aren't currently. I'd respectfully disagree with previous answers that keep the multiple calls to `geom_bar` and encourage you to instead reshape your data in line with the `ggplot` paradigm.
3. Only in rare cases should you refer back to the name of your data frame while using `ggplot`, other than `data =`. It can cause weird errors. So `x = TEMP_PREC_BIRR$year_month` should just be `x = year_month`.

Getting your data into a long format made me realize a couple things: you're currently comparing days of certain temperatures with days of certain precipitation levels. `fill` is then receiving both heavy precipitation and cool temperature, for example, but these aren't really comparable. You also have "medium" as a potential temperature and level of precipitation, which means they'll just get lumped together as the same thing in `fill`. You'll want to adjust those `type` labels accordingly.

Having two types of measures—precipitation and temperature—that you want to display together but which are not directly comparable is a good use case for faceting, which I do in this first example.

I'm getting the data into a long shape by `gather`ing twice, once to make a column of measure types (pre or tem), and once to get a column of values. Because of the levels issue with types duplicated across measure types, I'm using `interaction` to make types like "MEDIUM.pre" differentiable from "MEDIUM.tem". This is still less than ideal, because you're giving fill colors on the same scale but with different types of measures.

Then I call `facet_wrap(~ measure)` to show the two measure types as being related but not the same. If, in your larger dataset you have multiple locations, you could do `facet_grid(SOUNAME ~ measure)`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(
  SOUNAME = c("WATERFORD (TYCOR)", "WATERFORD (TYCOR)","WATERFORD (TYCOR)", "WATERFORD (TYCOR)", "WATERFORD (TYCOR)","WATERFORD (TYCOR)", "WATERFORD (TYCOR)", "WATERFORD (TYCOR)","WATERFORD (TYCOR)", "WATERFORD (TYCOR)", "WATERFORD (TYCOR)","WATERFORD (TYCOR)"), 
  year_month = c("2014-04", "2014-04", "2014-04","2014-04", "2014-05", "2014-05", "2014-05", "2014-05", "2014-06","2014-06", "2014-06", "2014-06"), 
  pre_type = c("NONE", "HEAVY","LIGHT", "MEDIUM", "NONE", "HEAVY", "LIGHT", "MEDIUM", "NONE","HEAVY", "LIGHT", "MEDIUM"), 
  pre_value = c(14L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 15L,3L, 10L, 3L, 17L, 2L, 9L, 2L), 
  tem_type = c("V_COLD", "COLD","HOT", "MEDIUM", "V_COLD", "COLD", "HOT", "MEDIUM", "V_COLD","COLD", "HOT", "MEDIUM"), 
  tem_value = c(0L, 30L, 0L, 0L, 0L,31L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 17L, 13L, 0L), 
  nb_species = c(NA, 8L, NA, NA,NA, 17L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), 
  .Names = c("SOUNAME", "year_month","pre_type", "pre_value", "tem_type", "tem_value", "nb_species"), 
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
  row.names = c(NA,-12L))

df %>%
  select(-nb_species) %>%
  gather(key = measure, value = type, pre_type, tem_type) %>%
  gather(key = pre_or_tem2, value = value, pre_value, tem_value) %>%
  select(-pre_or_tem2) %>%
  mutate(measure = str_extract(measure, "^[a-z]+")) %>%
  mutate(type = interaction(type, measure)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year_month, y = value, fill = type)) +
    geom_col(position = "stack") +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2") +
    facet_wrap(~ measure)
```

[image]

In the second example I do some editorializing. I noticed that there are only a limited number of combinations of temperature and precipitation, so I instead set up a column of the interactions between the two; grouping by this, plus `year_month`, lets you sum up the number of days with a combination of precipitation level and temperature. I mapped this interaction column to fill, and dropped the faceting. Again, if you have observations at multiple locations, you could make use of `facet_wrap(~ SOUNAME)`.

```r
df %>%
  select(-nb_species) %>%
  gather(key = measure, value = value, pre_value, tem_value) %>%
  mutate(measure = str_extract(measure, "^[a-z]+")) %>%
  mutate(pre_type = paste0(pre_type, "pre")) %>%
  mutate(tem_type = paste0(tem_type, "tem")) %>%
  select(-measure) %>%
  mutate(type = interaction(pre_type, tem_type)) %>%
  group_by(SOUNAME, year_month, type) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year_month, y = value, fill = type)) +
    geom_col() +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2")
```

[image]

Created on 2018-05-19 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Final note: I dropped the `nb_species` column just to simplify the data I was working with since it didn't appear in the plots; I used `geom_col()`, which is equivalent to `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`; and I used a Color Brewer palette because it was easier to differentiate with lots of colors. Feel free to ignore all of these steps.